# How to open external URL in a new tab from cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I want to open another url, lets say : 'localhost/test.html' from the page which is in cakePHP.

I already have a view(page.ctp) and controller(PagesController.php). On this page there is a button with name Wireshark, whenever I click on this button I want to go to another URL but not want to redirect to another page within the cakePHP server.

In the page.ctp I use this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Wireshark'), array('controller' => 'tests','action' => 'wireshark'))?>
```

In TestsController:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');


class TestsController extends AppController {

    public function wireshark() {

        }
    }
```

In wireshark.ctp:

```
<?php
echo "hello"
?>
```

Till now when I click on button it redirects me to "http://localhost:9877/tests/wireshark" and display "hello". I think it works fine but what I need is to go to another web page(localhost/test.html).

I also tried with this in the same file:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Wireshark'), 'localhost/test.html')?>
```

I get this when I use above code:

> Error: The requested address '/pages/localhost/test.html' was not found
>   on this server.

I am totally new and self studying cakePHP. I googled it but none of the post took me to the detailed explanation for how to do that(may be because I am so new to this).

Can anyone please help me with this. I am sorry if its not clear please ask me for clarification.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

prepend http:// to the url

```
<a href="http://localhost/test.html" target="_blank">
    Wireshark
</a>

<!-- or-->

<?= $this->Html->link(
    __('Wireshark'),
    'http://localhost/test.html',
    [
        'target' => '_blank',
    ]
) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) . I think I was not using http:// . After using http it is working now . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me explain.

1. The first keyword of `Wireshark` represent to the label of `href`
2. The second keyword call `Tests` is represent your controller and
3. The third keyword call `wiresha` is `action` of your controller

Hope this help for you.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Wireshark',array('controller'=>'Tests','action'=>'wireshark'), array('target'=>'_blank'));
```